# How to implement a custom termination in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to implement a custom termination class but I'm not able to inject my extension of the `TerminationConfig` class in order to get loaded and then read the custom fields required by the new termination (which are included in the solver config.xml).

I have already implemented both: a custom termination by extending `AbstractTermination` as well as an extension of `TerminationConfig`.

**The missing piece is how I tell to Optaplanner to use my custom config class**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TerminationConfig.setTerminationClass(myClass)`.

```
<termination>
  <terminationClass>org.foo.Bar</terminationClass>
</termination>
```

Or if that doesn't suffice, try

```
<termination class="org.foo.BarTerminationConfig">
  <barField>7</barField>
</termination>
```

- 1) **What does your custom termination do?** I want to understand the use case to evaluate if we can support it out of the box in a future version.
- 2) We can add `customProperties` support pretty easily. That would look like this:

  ```
  <termination>
    <terminationClass>org.foo.Bar</terminationClass>
    <customProperties>
      <barField>7</barField>
    </customerProperties>
  </termination>
  ```

  Notice no need for a BarConfig class. [Create a jira for it and link it here.](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/PLANNER)

Comment: With the first way (terminationClass) custom config params can't be passed to the custom termination. The 2nd way is throwing an unmarshalling error when I add the class property (I tried just extending the official TerminationConfig with no extra code)

Comment: The motivation: is because I have some cases (usually simple vrp problems) where no moves improves the score and the solver enters in an infinite loop in the LocalSearchDecider here
[link](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/842f034c1a0a2d6423eb523c16a33bdaebe9b04e/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/localsearch/decider/LocalSearchDecider.java#L108). My custom termination detects when the score is stuck in a phase step and avoids the infinite loop. Check the implementation here [link](https://gist.github.com/jdonzet/67bc38a059f9b54e5060e253007c560e).

Comment: PS: I don't want to use terminations by time